# Solving a transcendental equation using matlab

Tags: matlab, transcendental-equations

How to solve x = sin(ax+b), when 'a' and 'b' takes all the real values in [0,1]? Can I use matlab to solve it?

I have understood to solve the equation when 'a' and 'b' both are fixed constants. But, I wish to know whether we have to find a solution for each pair of (a,b). If so, how to put them all together?

Comment: Unless there's a special function describing the solution (which I don't think there is in this case), you're stuck with just looping through some iterative method for various values of $a$ and $b$ to get function values on a grid.

Comment: So, do you mean that we have to substitute the values of specific 'a' and 'b' in order to find the solutions? Could you assist me at least is there a way to generate a set of values for 'x' by fixing the value of 'a' and vary the value of 'b'?

Comment: I doubt it. But despite that, I could generate a plot of the solution as a function of $(a,b)$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ easily enough. Most of the time to do so would be taken by programming, not runtime.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any example of that kind?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function $f(x,y,z) = x-\sin(y x+z) = 0$ for $(-1\le x\le 1),( 0\le y\le 1), (0\le z\le 1)$ we can depict the following surface patch

[image]

Comment: Thank you much. This is beautiful. But I've a doubt here. As the equation is transcendental, there should be multiple branch points for x, for a given value of (y,z). But your curve is smooth. For an example, for y=0.3, z=1 and y=0.9,z=1, I get the same value for x, i.e, x=0.96. But how it is disregarded here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @VasanthG $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left ( x - \sin(ax+b) \right ) = 1-a\cos(ax+b) \geq 1-a>0$ if $a \in [0,1)$, so there is exactly one root. The same is true when $a=1$ but it takes just a hair more work to show.

Comment: Thank you @Ian, I'd verify the same and get back to you.